I am using .net core 8 and vue.js in my project. There is a "module not found" error. How can I fix?
I have an API that pulls data from two tables in my SQL database. Get, post, put, delete functions work with the help of swagger, but I'm having trouble connecting this project to vue.js.
The directory of the codes I wrote is as follows:
HospitalProject(This project is on my desktop)
│
├── vue
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── components
│   │   │   └── DoctorHospitalManagement.vue
│   │   ├── router
│   │   │   └── index.js
│   │   ├── App.vue
│   │   └── main.js
│   └── public
│       └── index.html
│ 
└── api
    ├── Controllers
    │   ├── DoctorController.cs
    │   └── HospitalController.cs
    └── ...

Here is my index.js file:
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import DoctorHospitalManagement from '../components/DoctorHospitalManagement.vue'
 
Vue.use(VueRouter)
 
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'DoctorHospitalManagement',
    component: DoctorHospitalManagement
  }
]
 
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})
 
export default router


"ERROR in ./src/router/index.js 3:0-81
I get the warning "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve".

I have checked the directory many times, but it still says it is not correct.

Where is the dot net part? Also how did you created your Vue project? Did you followed the official documentation?

Use of Vue.use() suggests Vue 2/Vue Router v3.x installation instructions were followed, whereas the post is tagged with vuejs3.  Consult Vue Router v4.x documentation for correct Vue 3 installation instructions.

.net part is in the api folder

double check the import file location name is correct or not and it exist at the "src/components/" folder. check app has enough permission to access the file. try to reinstall the dependencies after deleting it from the existing one. for a testing try to move DoctorHospitalManagement.vue temporarily to the same directory as your index.js file.
